# How to install APXS into existing Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I'm running an Apache 2.0.52 and I would like to install a new module. For this, I need the APXS (Apache Extension Tool).

It is not installed in my Apache version so I need to install it.

I don't have any internet access on the *server* so I cannot use `yum` or something similar.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to find the right package from your distribution which includes `apxs`. Your tags include redhat, so you're probably looking for something like `httpd-devel`. (I found the package name via Google: in general, packages related to building software will have -dev or -devel in their names.)

Download the correct package on another machine (distribution, machine architecture and version all need to match the version of the httpd package installed on the server), copy the file over, and install it with `rpm  -i filename.rpm`.

You might find that `rpm` complains about missing dependencies; if so, repeat the above for the missing packages. (Yum will handle dependencies automatically; this is one of its advantages!)

Comment: Hi Stephen, I have Raspbian Jessie and apache2 v 2.2.7 , and I cant locate axpx in the install location of apache2 , do you have any idea what it might be called in apache2 of raspbian or where it might be located ?